# How to use app.service('myService') inside a FeathersJS service extension?

Tags: javascript, feathersjs

I am trying to extend `find()` method for a service named `properties` in my FeathersJS app.

What I need is appending in all records returned by `find()` an array with integers coming from another service named `propertyadds`. This means I need to change my response from

```
{
  "total": 2973,
  "limit": 10,
  "skip": 0,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      ...
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      ...
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

to

```
{
  "total": 2973,
  "limit": 10,
  "skip": 0,
  data: [
    {
      "id": 1,
      ...
      "additionals": [10,20,30]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      ...
      "additionals": [12,25,33]
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

where the values in additionals come from service `propertyadds`, which manages a table like

```
| property_id | additional_id |
|-------------|---------------|
|      1      |       10      |
|      1      |       20      |
|      1      |       30      |
|      2      |       12      |
|      2      |       25      |
|      2      |       33      |
|-------------|---------------|
```

My initial idea was extending `properties` service like this

```
const { Service } = require('feathers-sequelize');

exports.Properties = class Properties extends Service {
  async find(data,params) {
      let newResponse = await super.find(data,params);
      let newData = newResponse.data.map(async pr => {
          pr.additionals = await app.service('propertyadds').find({
              properti_id: pr.id
          })
          return pr;
      })
      return {
          total: newResponse.total,
          limit: newResponse.limit,
          skip: newResponse.skip,
          data: newData
      }
  }
};
```

The problem is I don't have `app` inside `src/services/properties/properties.class.js` and (being new to FeathersJS as I am) I don't know how to get it.

What do I need to have a valid `app` const accessing all services inside this module?

Comment: Thanks for the edition, @ishenwood!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was, in fact, achieved when I visited `src/services/properties.service.js` and found out this line

```
app.use('/properties', new Properties(options, app));
```

So, service `properties` was, in fact, receiving an `app` object in its creation.

Learning this made me see the correct solution, written in `src/services/properties/properties.class.js` like this:

```
const { Service } = require('feathers-sequelize');

exports.Properties = class Properties extends Service {

    constructor(options, app) {
        super(options, app);
        this.app = app;
    }

    async find(data, params) {
        let oldRes = await super.find(data, params);
        let newResData = oldRes.data.map(async pr => {
            let includedRecords = await this.app.service('propertyadds').find({
                query: {
                    property_id: pr.id
                }
            })
            pr.additionals = includedRecords.map(e => e.additional_id).sort();
            return pr;
        })
        return await Promise.all(newResData)
            .then(completed => {
                return {
                    total: oldRes.total,
                    limit: oldRes.limit,
                    skip: oldRes.skip,
                    data: completed
                }
            })
    }
}
```

As it may be seen, it was a matter of creating a `constructor` method for the extended Properties class, in order to expose the `app` object in `this.app`. This may be done after calling `super(options,app)` to make `this` available.

After this it was just a matter of using `this.app` to create an instance of the other service and then making the correct async calls.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for feather-sequelize but according to [doc](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html#setup-app-path)

*For services registered before app.listen is invoked, the setup function of each registered service is called on invoking app.listen...*

By inheritating from `Service` (I don't know if that the standard way to do), maybe  `Service` implements  `setup` and you may access `this.app` from within `Properties::find()`

If you don't have it then write it:

```
async find(data,params) {
...
}
async setup(app, path){
  await super.setup && super.setup(app, path)
  // for now no setup on Service
  // should Service adds a setup, it is unlikely that it wraps app to a 
  // whole new object and assigns it to this, so we can still
  // assign app to this with a relative confidence
  this.app = app
}
```

Comment: maybe I'm doing this wrong, but when I tried this all I got was an error. `super.setup(app, path) TypeError: (intermediate value).setup is not a function`...

Comment: sorry about that, sequelize::Service does not define a setup, so no need to call the parent method

Comment: So, how may I get a valid app object? Or I can't do that?

Comment: You can try above version or just ```setup(app){this.app = app}``` as done in the doc. If you update feathers-sequelize one day, and for some obscure reason it now implements a setup, it is better to call it... but for now you are "safe" either way