# After hook for find() not working properly in FeathersJS

Tags: promise, hook, feathersjs

I'm trying to solve the problem described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59361549/how-to-use-app-servicemyservice-inside-a-feathersjs-service-extension).

Extending presented so many caveats that I decided to try an after hook for `find()` and wrote this

```
async function findAdditionals(context) {
  const { result, app } = context;
  let newResultData = result.data.map(async pr => {
    let includedRecords = await app.service('propertyadds').find({
      query: {
        property_id: pr.id
      }
    })
    pr.additionals = includedRecords.map(e => e.additional_id);
    return pr;
  })
  Promise.all(newResultData).then(completed => {
    return Object.assign({},context,{result: {
      total: result.total,
      limit: result.limit,
      skip: result.skip,
      data: completed
    }})
  });
}
```

I used `Promise.all` based on [this post here](https://medium.com/@ian.mundy/async-map-in-javascript-b19439f0099).

But this is not working at all! When I perform a request GET http://localhost:3030/properties, which is the route for the service I am using, I just get the same old response, without the appended data I need.

What am I missing?

Comment: You may just have a missing `return` before `Promise.all(......)`. Without it, findAdditionals's caller will not await the function's async activity.

Comment: Yes. In fact, `return await`, since I must have all resolved before returning.

Comment: `await` is unnecessary. A simple `return Promise.all(...)` will do the job.

Comment: Curiously it didn't... I tried and it returned all undefined. With await it worked perfectly. I gave up using a hook and extended the Properties service. My solution is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59361549/how-to-use-app-servicemyservice-inside-a-feathersjs-service-extension/59362057?noredirect=1#comment104919586_59362057 and it only worked with await. Please don't ask me why! LOL

Comment: Doesn't make sense.

Comment: You should really avoid mixing `await` and `.then()` syntaxes. Therefore it would be better to write `let completed = Promise.all(newResultData); return Object.assign({}, context, ....);`.

Comment: As soon as I deliver the current project I'll perform an investigation about this. I know it doesn't make sense. just like lots of things in live and in Javascript, you know. Thanks for the advice anyway.

Comment: Sounds like a dodgy javascript engine.

Comment: Possibly. Or better saying, probably!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the function to run properly you have to actually `return` a Promise, in your case the `Promise.all`:

```
async function findAdditionals(context) {
  const { result, app } = context;
  let newResultData = result.data.map(async pr => {
    let includedRecords = await app.service('propertyadds').find({
      query: {
        property_id: pr.id
      }
    })
    pr.additionals = includedRecords.map(e => e.additional_id);
    return pr;
  })

  return Promise.all(newResultData).then(completed => {
    return Object.assign({},context,{result: {
      total: result.total,
      limit: result.limit,
      skip: result.skip,
      data: completed
    }})
  });
}
```

However, Feathers will not do anything with that method. Only the methods [described in the service interface](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html) will be mapped to REST endpoints. Extending existing classes is described [in the guide](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/basics/services.html#customizing-a-service) and the [database adapter API](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/common.html#classes-es6) and the same as extending any other JavaScript class.

And alternative is to use a [hook](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html#quick-example) on the `find` method and set [context.result](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html#context-result).

Comment: I solved the problem by extending the corresponding service, as you may see in my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59361549/how-to-use-app-servicemyservice-inside-a-feathersjs-service-extension

Comment: It is now running smoothly and I even created another extensions to a few services. Pretty easy after the first one.